# Use of 時{とき} in the following sentences

Tags: grammar

So, I've been told by a native Japanese that the following sentence sounds weird:

- LA VITA E'BELLAを見{み}る[時]{とき}、[感動]{かんどう}しました。

In her own words, 'because watching that video is a one time thing and not your habit, so we usually use the past tense.'

But in my book, it says that in a A時、B sentence, we use the present short form when A happens after or at the time of B.  And I want to say that I got emotional when I watched that film (at the same time, not after the film).  So, could anybody explain to me in more detail whether the sentence is correct or not, and why?

Comment: That's a good movie!

Answer (score 4):

When you are moved by a movie, you have already watched the movie. You remember the scenes, music, and the story.

> LA VITA E'BELLAを見る時

implies when you were moved, LA VITA E'BELLA **hadn't finished** yet. So it sounds like you were moved by something else (such as equipment of the theater or behavior of the audience) during the movie or just before it started.

> LA VITA E'BELLAを見た時

This means that you **had watched** LA VITA E'BELLA when you were moved, that is, you were moved probably by the movie itself.